# How to update multiple instances efficiently in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Company` model that have `lending_restricted:boolean` column.
The list about the restriction are collected by `restricted_codes` method.

And to update only necessary companies, I wrote like this:

```
old_codes = Company.where(lending_restricted: true).pluck(:code)
new_codes = restricted_codes
(new_codes - old_codes).each do |code|
  c = Company.find_by(code: code)
  c.try(:update_attributes, lending_restricted: true)
end
(old_codes - new_codes).each do |code|
  c = Company.find_by(code: code)
  c.try(:update_attributes, lending_restricted: false)
end
```

It works basically fine, but I feel it's a bit redundant to write similar function two times.
Is there better way to write a method like this?

The number of `restricted_codes` is about 100, and there are about 4000 companies in my Rails project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but perhaps something like this? I've also updated your code so it's done in one query (instead of N queries).

```
def update_lending_restriction(codes, restriction)
  Company.where(code: codes).update_all(lending_restricted: restriction)
end

old_codes = Company.where(lending_restricted: true).pluck(:code)
new_codes = restricted_codes

update_lending_restriction(new_codes - old_codes, true)
update_lending_restriction(old_codes - new_codes, false)
```